Disjoint Open Sets and Their Closed Supersets
I am working on a problem that I believe requires a disproof, but I'm unsure of where to begin. The problem is as follows:
Prove or Disprove: If nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ are open and $A \cap B=\varnothing$, then there exist sets $A_c$ and $B_c$ such that $A \subsetneq A_c$ and $B \subsetneq B_c$, where $A_c$ and $B_c$ are closed and $A_c \cap B_c=\varnothing$.
I suspect that this statement may be false, but I am uncertain about the correct approach to demonstrate this. Any guidance or suggestions on how to start tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Consider the discrete 2-point space.

Suppose you have an example that disproves the statement.  Can you say anything about this example?

@BenSteffan The smallest counterexample has three points, so I don't know what you're trying to say to OP.

@BrianMoehring The smallest counterexample is the discrete 2-point space. Please read the question again carefully, paying mind to the $\subsetneq$'s (if those read as $\subseteq$'s then you would be correct).

@BenSteffan Fair.  Yes, I missed that, but I hope you'd agree it's a bit of a squirrel-ly counterexample that sidesteps the more nuanced topological issue.

@BenSteffan sorry, but I could not understand your point.

@bruno The discrete 2-point space is a counterexample to your statement as written. I'll leave it to you to figure out what the respective sets should be (since you're asking for guidance; I can also spell it out in an answer if you'd prefer).

@BenSteffan Now I would prefer an answer because I tried what you have said but couldn’t handle unfortunately.

Here's a minimal counterexample to the question as stated: Let $X = \{x, y\}$ be the two-point space equipped with the discrete topology, and define $A = \{x\}$ and $B = \{y\}$. Then $A \cap B = \emptyset$, but clearly disjoint sets $A \subsetneq A_c$, $B \subsetneq B_c$ cannot exist: The space only has two points, so any superset of $A$ or $B$ already has to be all of $X$!

This example is admittedly a bit contrived, exploiting the fact that you specified that $A_c$ and $B_c$ should be proper supersets of $A$ and $B$, respectively. But even if you weaken the condition to $A \subseteq A_c$ and $B \subseteq B_c$ there are plenty of counterexamples: For instance, let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = (-\infty, 0)$ and $B = (0, \infty)$.
